# SELECT with where between not working as expected

Tags: mariadb, select, mariadb-10.5

I'm trying to use this query, to filter between the names C89 to C110.

```
SELECT id FROM servers WHERE server_name BETWEEN 'C89' AND 'C110'
```

But this doesn't work. If I change c89 to c90, it at least selects the two servers. It's like it's only using the first 2 numbers in the calculation.

Can anyone help me ? I'm using mariadb 10.5 I'm looking for a solution that doesn't need to add a lot of words into the query. To be as lean as possible for readability

Comment: When sorting strings, 'C89' comes after 'C110'. If you need to sort it both alphabetically and numerically then you’re going to have to do the work.

Comment: There is no possible string that would be sorted between 'c89' and 'c110'. You would need to do something like `where server_name like 'C%' and cast(substring(server_name,2) as number) between 89 and 110`. The actual functions you use would depend on your unknown RDBMS.

Comment: Normalize servers names, make their numeric part lengths equal by zero-padding. For example, if servers names values numeric parts are not longer than 3 digits then convert `C89` to `C089`. After this BETWEEN will act as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shorter answer:

```
... WHERE MID(server, 2) BETWEEN 89 AND 110
```

Or, if you need to limit to the "C" set of servers:

```
... WHERE MID(server, 2) BETWEEN 89 AND 110
      AND server LIKE "C%"
```

Or (to avoid trouble with "24H1"),

```
... WHERE IF(server LIKE "C%", 
             MID(server, 2) BETWEEN 89 AND 110,
             FALSE)
```

Oh, now I see another 'bad' server name (`INT1`).  Face it, you need to put some of the burden on the DBA.  He must realize that the practical way is to say

```
... WHERE server BETWEEN 'C89'  AND 'C99'
       OR server BETWEEN 'C100' AND 'C110'
```

That is, break up the filtering into as many ranges as needed so that *string* comparisons will work, and *do not* think numeric.

Comment: @Freedo - Are there 3 ways to identify a server?  `id`, `server`, _and_ `server_name`?

Comment: @Freedo - There's a lot of `TEXT` columns; they may lead to performance issues (because of how large columns are stored 'off record').  Anyway, I added a 4th way to do the query; this is simple enough to explain to a DBA and depend on him to "meet the problem halfway" rather than depending on some complex SQL to do all the work.

Comment: @Freedo - Your example is caught between a rock and a hard space:  Server names are arbitrary strings, yet the query is applying some "meaning" (namely 'C' followed by a number) to those strings.  If it were "group C, server number 89", then having 2 columns would make the `WHERE` obvious and efficient.  And "24H" could be another 'group' name.  Freelance:  mysql at rjweb dot org .

Comment: you can delete your comments now. I'll remove this later

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, when comparing strings, they are compared [**lexicographically**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45950646/5059085) not **numerically** (even when they contain numerical values). What this means is each character is compared to the comparison string's character of the same index. For example, comparing the strings "10" and "3" would result in "10" preceding "3" because "1" comes before "3". I'm not sure if this is applicable to MariaDB, but in other RDBMS you can usually reference an [ASCII table](https://cs.smu.ca/%7Eporter/csc/ref/asciifull.gif) when unsure of what the ordering for one character vs another (notice capital letters preceded lower case).

If all servers' `server_name` start with letter 'C' then you can use the [`REPLACE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replace-function/) function in MariaDB to get rid of the 'C' and then cast the string to an INT like so:

```
SELECT id 
FROM servers 
WHERE REPLACE(server_name, 'C', '')
    BETWEEN 89 AND 110
```

Comment: Change `server` to `CAST(REPLACE(server, 'C', '') AS UNSIGNED)`.

Comment: @RickJames Sorry I don't follow? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If servers C90, C91...C109 are expected to be included (and because they are using BETWEEN I would be very surprised if they weren't) then your query will miss them and only select C90 and C110. @RickJames query gives the numbers of all the servers, as does his answer.

Comment: @simonatrcl How do you figure that, when I'm casting `89` and `110` to integers before using the `BETWEEN` clause?

Comment: @RickJames Right, missed that, thanks!